# How to add object property with Jena? Special format

Tags: java, rdf, jena, owl, object-property

Hello I am trying to add an object property between this two individuals. I also have the object property in the code and the individuals are in the ontology. In only need to connect them using a property. The individuals look like this in the code, my problem is that I have never work with that ontologies using this "Description" tag.

```xml
<!-- http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/n6356 -->

<owl:Thing rdf:about="http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/n6356">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&bibo;Article"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&bibo;Document"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&vivo;ConferencePaper"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&vivo;InformationResource"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;NamedIndividual"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en-us">Indiana University Digital Music Library Project</rdfs:label>
    <vitro:modTime rdf:datatype="&xsd;dateTime">2010-07-28T15:36:03</vitro:modTime>
    <vitro:moniker rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">conference paper</vitro:moniker>
    <bibo:doi rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/379437.379774</bibo:doi>
    <title>Indiana University Digital Music Library Project</title>
    <dateTimeValue rdf:resource="http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/n4086167"/>
    <bibo:presentedAt rdf:resource="http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/n5092"/>
    <informationResourceInAuthorship rdf:resource="http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/n6257"/>
    <informationResourceInAuthorship rdf:resource="http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/n6300"/>
    <vitro:mostSpecificType rdf:resource="&vivo;ConferencePaper"/>
</owl:Thing>

<!-- http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/n6399 -->

<owl:Thing rdf:about="http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/n6399">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&bibo;Article"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&bibo;Document"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&vivo;ConferencePaper"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&vivo;InformationResource"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;NamedIndividual"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en-us">Assessing Future Ecosystem Services: a Case Study of the Northern Highlands Lake District  Wisconsin</rdfs:label>
    <vitro:modTime rdf:datatype="&xsd;dateTime">2010-07-28T15:36:03</vitro:modTime>
    <vitro:moniker rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">conference paper</vitro:moniker>
    <bibo:doi rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/379437.99999</bibo:doi>
    <title>Assessing Future Ecosystem Services: a Case Study of the Northern Highlands Lake District  Wisconsin</title>
    <dateTimeValue rdf:resource="http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/n111111"/>
    <bibo:presentedAt rdf:resource="http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/n2222"/>
    <informationResourceInAuthorship rdf:resource="http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/n3333"/>
    <informationResourceInAuthorship rdf:resource="http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/n4444"/>
    <vitro:mostSpecificType rdf:resource="&vivo;ConferencePaper"/>
</owl:Thing>
```

I have tried with this code but the getters give me null values. Getting the two individuals by its names, getting the object property and adding them to the model.

```java
Individual doc = model.getIndividual("n6356");
Individual ref = model.getIndividual("n6399");
ObjectProperty cites = model.getObjectProperty("http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/cites");
model.add(doc,cites,ref);
```

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Answer (score 2):

Resources in RDF are either blank nodes or URI nodes.  Your individuals happen to be IRI nodes, so you need to retrieve them as such with:

```
Individual doc = model.getIndividual("http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/n6356");
Individual ref = model.getIndividual("http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/n6399");
```

If you're going to do a lot of this, it probably makes sense to do:

```
final String NS = "http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/";
Individual doc = model.getIndividual(NS+"n6356");
Individual ref = model.getIndividual(NS+"n6399");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't save your Model in Memory, don't forget to write it out.

```
final String NS = "http://vivo.iu.edu/individual/";
Individual doc = model.getIndividual(NS+"n6356");
Individual ref = model.getIndividual(NS+"n6399");
ObjectProperty cites = model.getObjectProperty("http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/cites");
model.add(doc,cites,ref).write(new FileOutputStream(new File("rdf/myRDFFile.owl"));
```